# Unique Constraint Allow Null for One column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, constraints, ddl

I have the following Table Structure

```
tbl_exam (Year,ExamCode,RollNo)
```

1). Data in Table is:

```
(2017,1,NULL)
(2017,1,NULL)  
(2017,1,1)
(2017,1,2)
```

**Allow the above values**

2).

```
(2017,1,1)
(2017,1,1) **Not Allowed**
```

**How to add Unique Constraint which allows null value for RollNo Column**

***Edit: Need Composite Key Constraint***

**Solved:** 
Thanks To **David Aldridge**

```
create unique index exam_uidx on tbl_exam
(
Nvl2(RollNo, Year    , null),
Nvl2(RollNo, Exam_Code, null),
RollNo
)
```

Comment: Edit: Need Composite Key Constraint

Comment: You can't. If you add a unique constraint based on those three keys then the first two records you show will clearly be the same. I suspect that the data model is incorrect and either you shouldn't be entering a record when the RollNo is null or you need a surrogate key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that you could do this by placing a unique constraint on:

```
(
  Nvl2(RollNo, Year    , null),
  Nvl2(RollNo, ExamCode, null),
  RollNo
)
```

Not tested

Comment: Thanks David Aldridge

Comment: @S.NisarAhmad, if this answered your question, please mark it as Correct.